# Binding UserControls Canvas.GetTop between 2 Canvases

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I have 2 Canvases, canvasA and canvasB, resideing within the same LayoutControl.

In my code, I populate canvasA with TextEdit UserControls using data from a database. These are the parent Labels.

The children Labels are also populated from the database but in canvasB. These children are in the same Canvas.Top position as it's parent, but the Canvas.Left position is calculated and set.

I'm wondering if there a way of binding the Top position of the parent Labels in canvasA with the corresponding children Labels in canvasB. I have tried:

```
Dim topBinding As New Binding
topBinding.Source = parentLabel
topBinding.Path = New PropertyPath("topPosition")
topBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
topBinding.IsAsync = True

Me.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, topBinding)
```

These codes are in the childLabel.Loaded and parentLabel is passed in. The topPosition is just a property that stores the current "Top" position of the parent Label

I have also tried

```
Dim topBinding As New Binding
topBinding.Source = parentLabel
topBinding.Path = New PropertyPath("Canvas.TopProperty")
topBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
topBinding.IsAsync = True

Me.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, topBinding)
```

and also

```
Me.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, Canvas.GetTop(parentTextEdit))
```

but nothing works. The children are all at 0 for the "Top" position.

I have resorted to doing a Canvas.SetTop(childLabel, parentLabel.topPosition) .

Is there a way to making binding work for this? So that later when I need to move the parent Labels around (the Y axis only), I don't have to calculate and move each childLabel.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use a Grid with two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work like this (with `Canvas.TopProperty` not being a string):

```
Dim topBinding As New Binding
topBinding.Source = parentLabel
topBinding.Path = New PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty)
Me.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, topBinding)
```

Or this (as Canvas.Top is an attached property):

```
Dim topBinding As New Binding
topBinding.Source = parentLabel
topBinding.Path = New PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)")
Me.SetBinding(Canvas.TopProperty, topBinding)
```